# const-correctness - инициализация переменных внутри класса

Tags: map, const

Кто-нибудь видит здесь проблему в const-correctness?

```
class iterator {
    private:
        Node<Pair>* _ptr/* = nullptr */;
        MtmMap<ValueType, KeyType, CompareFunction>* _map_ptr;
    public:
        iterator(Node<Pair>* ptr, const MtmMap<ValueType, KeyType, CompareFunction> * mtm_ptr)
            : _ptr(ptr), _map_ptr(mtm_ptr){ }
```

Компилятор кричит:

> cannot convert from 'const MtmMap *' to 'MtmMap *'

И, наверное, поэтому же:

> 'mtm::MtmMap::iterator::_map_ptr:' : member could not be initialized

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете присваивать значение указателя на константный объект указателю на неконстантный объект.

Так что компилятор вам правильно говорит об ошибке в конструкторе

```
iterator(Node<Pair>* ptr, const MtmMap<ValueType, KeyType, CompareFunction> * mtm_ptr)
                    : _ptr(ptr), _map_ptr(mtm_ptr){ }
```

так как параметр `mtm_ptr` у вас - это указатель на константный объект

```
const MtmMap<ValueType, KeyType, CompareFunction> * mtm_ptr
```

а член данных класса `_map_ptr` - это указатель на неконстантный объект

```
MtmMap<ValueType, KeyType, CompareFunction>* _map_ptr;
```

Поэтому инициализация `_ptr(ptr)` некорректная.

Вот более упрощенный демонстрационный пример

```
int main()
{
    const int x = 10;
    const int *cp = &x;
    int *p = cp;
}
```

Компилятор выдаст сообщение на подобие данного

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:5:14: error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]
     int *p = cp;
              ^
```

так как иначе вы получаете возможность изменить константный объект через указатель на неконстантный объект, что в общем случае ведет к неопределенному поведению программы. Поэтому такое неявное преобразование запрещено стандартом C++.